# Visual Stidio 2015 # pragma comment (linker, "/EXPORT options

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

```
Visual Stuio 2015 #pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT  options
```

After migration to X64 I had to remove the following pragmas

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/EXPORT:DllCanUnloadNow=_DllCanUnloadNow@0,PRIVATE")
#pragma comment(linker,/EXPORT:DllGetClassObject=_DllGetClassObject@12,PRIVATE")
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:DllRegisterServer=_DllRegisterServer@0,PRIVATE")
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:DllUnregisterServer=_DllUnregisterServer@0,PRIVATE")
```

To solve the following unresolved external symbols:

```
1>NmsCmCommon.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllCanUnloadNow@0
1>NmsCmCommon.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllGetClassObject@12
1>NmsCmCommon.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllRegisterServer@0
1>NmsCmCommon.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllUnregisterServer@0
```

Wat are these pragmas for and what problems can happen if they are removed?

Comment: Your COM server won't work anymore when you remove them. First thing you should have noticed is that you couldn't register it anymore since DllRegisterServer() is no longer exported. [Using a .def file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a8cb12d-d1cb-4cc4-944a-e534b9ec1a6c/exporting-dllregisterserver?forum=vclanguage) is the correct way. Or remove the name decoration from the symbols, when you target x64 then this decoration hack is no longer necessary and the symbol turns from `_DllRegisterServer@0` into plain `DllRegisterServer`.

Comment: That helped after using the following Def File
; This .DEF file will be used for all proxy stubs

;LIBRARY 
EXPORTS
  DllCanUnloadNow PRIVATE
  DllGetClassObject PRIVATE
  DllRegisterServer PRIVATE
  DllUnregisterServer PRIVATE
   the problem was solved

Comment: now i us e def File with the following content:
        EXPORTS
        DllCanUnloadNow     @1 PRIVATE
        DllGetClassObject   @2 PRIVATE
        DllRegisterServer   @3 PRIVATE
        DllUnregisterServer     @4 PRIVATE
          
        That seams to work but i get a Warning Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning LNK4229 invalid directive '/DEF:../../Src/ToolLib/CommonProxyStub.def' encountered; ignored NmsCmCommon D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\Src\Cm\NmsCmCommon\NmsCmCommonPs.obj 1 
 i hope it is stll corrktle exported

Answer (score 0):

Now I see the Problem without the pagmas

```
pragma comment(linker,"/EXPORT:DllCanUnloadNow=_DllCanUnloadNow@0,PRIVATE")
pragma comment(linker,/EXPORT:DllGetClassObject=_DllGetClassObject@12,PRIVATE")
pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:DllRegisterServer=_DllRegisterServer@0,PRIVATE")
pragma omment(linker,"/EXPORT:DllUnregisterServer=_DllUnregisterServer@0,PRIVATE")
```

Are needed without them  can not register my dll with regsv32  because the function llRegisterServer is missing- So i have to implement this Function bot why this works only for X86 and not for X64 even if there where no  source changes and only some adaption of the project