# can not register NmsCmCommon.dll using regsvr32

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, x86-64

I have Windows 10, 64-bit.

I'm trying to register  NmsCmCommon.dll using regsvr32. "C:\WINDOWS\System32\regsvr32.exe  /C  NmsCmCommon.dll" but I get the following error:

The modules NmsCmCommon.dll is loaded but the entry-point DLLRegistryServer was not found.
Make sure that NmsCmCommn.dll is a valid DLL or OCX File and the try again.

I have run the command under  System32 and I have run my commands with "Run As Administrator".

The NmsCmCommon.dll was build with Visual Studio 2015 and migrated from X86  to X64 an still works in the X86  Version. when e compare the X64 an the X86 Version the only relevant change seams to be the Projects settings is that possible is there a setting which can cause this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52639812/17034

Comment: The /C is not the Problem ( i tried without) the problem is that the Function DLLRegistryServer is no more exported se my erlier post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639812/visual-stidio-2015-pragma-commentlinker-export-options

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you use /C for regsvr32? This isn't a valid argument.
2. This file isn't probably made for registering? Maybe it doesn't support COM.
3. Maybe this is a .NET module and needs to be registered with REGASM.